# OpenCV2.4.2 unhandled exception on VideoCapture

Tags: opencv, cmake

I just installed OpenCV2.4.2 and created an OpenCV project using CMake. I don't get any compilation errors. I have several functions for processing images and I have 2 applications:

1- Processes data from a video

2- Processes simulated data.

Both applications are identical except from the data extraction from the video.

**PROBLEM**: The application processing video crashes with

> Unhandled exception at 0x75d8a048 in program.exe Access violation
>   reading location 0x049f08c0.

It crashes in this part of the code, when reading frames:

```
cv::VideoCapture _video;
while(1) 
{       
        // grab the frame
        _video >> frame;  <-------------CRASHES HERE
                processFrame(frame);
}
```

So I guess there could be a problem with `cv::VideoCapture` class in OpenCV 2.4.2. How can I detect the problem and solve it?

**EDIT**

With video camera I managed to catch the error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\
src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 268
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowR
ange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\open
cv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 283
```

Comment: Need to see some actual code of yours.

Comment: you can debug and see what exactly happened

Comment: I tried another video and it works, but the video is a pink screen, nothing to do with the original. Could be something with the codecs? I use video.avi

Comment: @CarlosCachalote Are you running in **Debug** mode? Because it could be you are missing the debug dll of opencv_ffmpeg242

Answer (score 4):

Are you checking if the capture actually opened the file/camera ?

```
    if(_video.isOpened()) {  // check if capture succeeded
      // do stuff
    }
```

Not all codecs are supported per default. This depends on the library you use underneath to open the video. (This might be ffmpeg or quicktime).

Also you can catch the exception yourself, just to be on the safe side for future problems

```
try {
    _video >> frame;
} catch (cv::Exception) {
    cout << "An exception has accurred" << endl;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I am checking and it is opened. I use recorded video. Everything is done right because I use this code with OpenCV 2.3.1 and it didn't give problems

Comment: It's probably an issue with the video library used, running it though a debugger will give you more insight at which call, and with which video subsystem it actually causes trouble.

Comment: I tried the exception handler but the program crashes and stops so the exception is not catched. It stops at the second line of your code...

Comment: Build your code linking against the opencv ''debug libraries'' and set a breakpoint at the _video >> frame line. Then start a debugger, run the program and once hitting the breakpoint step through the call on the >> operator. It should give you some insight why there's an access to protected/wrong memory object.

Comment: Yes I always debug this way, but once the program breaks I can do nothing. Step into is not working. It is giving a violation reading location so I cannot continue debugging, only break.

Comment: One possibility could be that the linkage is broken between the subsystems (you're linking against an older version of a dll). Since some codecs seem to work and some crash the system. The decoder should throw an error and not crash. What you might want to do is to re-build opencv with video support (in case a re-install won't fix the problem)

Comment: I have tried with camera, and now I managed to catch the exception, I edit the post.