# OpenCv 2.4.8 Unhandled exception on VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I use this code and it just displays the video into a frame but when I execute this code I gets this Unhandled exception.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat image;
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
namedWindow("Window",1);
while (1)
{
    cap>>image;
    imshow("Window",image);
    waitKey(100);
}

return 0;
}
```

**Unhandled exception at at 0x00007FFF945FAB78 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000099DFC1F3B0.**

What can I do to escape from this unhandled exception & display the video correctly?

***Note : Using OpenCv 2.4.8 , V.S.2012 x64***

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV2.4.2 unhandled exception on VideoCapture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352904/opencv2-4-2-unhandled-exception-on-videocapture)

Comment: sometimes I had those kind of strange exception in visual studio express when I hadn't provided opencv dlls to the folder with the executable... That was strange because in vs pro those occurred as "Could not find opencv_xyz.dll" and in vs express as unhandled exception.

Comment: My operating system is x64 but vs is installed in Programms(x86) i tried to work on both but the same result the camera light is on and unhandled exception

Comment: But you've got vs express or professional?

Comment: i don't know but please tell what it will affect in both
and do you think it's up to the version i mean should i try earlier version or what ?!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

check VS dependencies,
project/*projectname* configuration/ linke/input
in address check lib name.